# Can I use gollum to create a wiki which isn't hosted by Github?

Tags: ruby, gollum-wiki

I want to create a wiki with gollum and push it to my own git repo, is that possible?

I created a new git repo, install gollum and started it. I got the "edit/Home" page. I added some content, saved...all looked good. Even the "revision history" showed that revisions occurred.

Then I stopped gollum and found there was nothing new in my git repo, I even checked if stuff hadn't been pushed...nothing. I'm not sure how/where it's storing the content that I add when I run it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Gollum will not sync with a git remote. It will never perform `git pull` or `git push`. You must have gollum running *on the remote server*, or you must manually run `git push` on machines where you make edits, and `git pull` on machines who also want to see the wiki. This could be part of a cron job if you're running locally.

It is much easier to have the gollum process running on your web server. See below for more information:

http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2012/05/15/personal-wiki-using-github-and-gollum-on-os-x/#toc-synchronization-with-github

Answer (score 0):

May be you are checking a wrong repository, the default is for gollum to use or create a git repository at the root of page files. It can be changed with the options `--page-file-dir` and `--base-path` (cf `gollum --help`)